# Splitting A String into two parts

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a string of four numbers 1123 that happens to be a set of a larger string, but I want to work on splitting that part first. In theory, I want to split 1123 into two parts separated by a space: 11 23 before I convert it to a letter using an Alphabet to Number Cypher. I see that there is a built in Split function for strings in Mathematica, but I do not see how I can split a string directly halfway across the length. What loop system can I use and what syntax will let me split my string of numbers into two parts? Any accurate answer helps, thank you!

Comment: [`StringPartition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringPartition.html) is what you are looking for, rather than `StringSplit`. Try `StringPartition["1123", 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

A list of even-length strings:

```
list = {"12", "1234", "123456", "12345678"};
```

You can use [`StringInsert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringInsert.html):

```
StringInsert[#, " ", 1 + StringLength[#]/2] & /@ list
```

> {"1 2", "12 34", "123 456", "1234 5678"}

Alternatively, you can use a combination of [`StringPartition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringPartition.html) and [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html):

```
StringRiffle[StringPartition[#, StringLength[#]/2]] & /@ list
```

> {"1 2", "12 34", "123 456", "1234 5678"}